# How to avoid 'This type of file can harm your computer' pop up in chrome autoamtion using selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I am using selenium to automate website filling in chrome. When I download exe or XML files I am getting a popup 'This type of file can harm your computer' with keep and discard options. How to disable this programmatically ?
I am implementing this in c#, 
I have tried,

```
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true")
```

But this is not working for me.
How to disable this popup ?
If not possible how to accept the warning ? 
Please help me.

Comment: Probably what you need is `chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "false")` instead to block the popup window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the message, you need to set the preference `safebrowsing.enabled` to `true`. Here is a working example with CSharp:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", "C:\\Downloads");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1602.exe");
```

And for a description of the preferences:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you need is change

```
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true")     // disables blocking the popup
```

to

```
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "false")   // enables blocking the popup
```

instead to avoid the popup window.

***Edit*** : In case you are getting stuck with the harmful file contents, you can try and set an *experimental chrome options* using :

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true");
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Quoting a sample from the doc [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) :

> Set a Chrome preference
>
> ```
> ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
> Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
> prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
> options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
> ```

***Date - 4 June,2016 [C#]***

Went through few links and could figure this out that `.Net` still doesn't have an `setExperimentalOption` preferences along with the ChromeOptions. So, one of the way to [Add Argument to the ChromeOptions using C#](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions_AddArgument.htm) with the flags listed [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) would be :

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
```

> Disables safebrowsing feature that checks download url and downloads
>   content's hash to make sure the content are not malicious.

***Date - 4 June,2016 [JAVA]***

The document [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setExperimentalOption-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) quotes it as :

> **public void setExperimentalOption(java.lang.String name,
>                                     java.lang.Object value)**
>
> Sets an experimental option. Useful for new ChromeDriver options *not yet
>   exposed through the ChromeOptions API*.

Comment: It is an age old issue - double negatives! :)

Comment: @kyle_engineer I know its an old isuue, but none of the suggested solutions are working. Can you answer to my question ?

Comment: Sorry @ITresearcher , I don't have any experience affecting Chrome programmatically, nor do I know the settings. But I imagine Google wouldn't make it easy to suppress a warning for potentially malicious software. That borders on a security rapture and generally browsers don't allow the site to affect those directly. The whole point of user interaction is to validate the risk.

Comment: ok. I think that's possible in some other way.. there are many developers working with selenium and chrome driver.

Comment: 'setExperimentalOption' is not a member of 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions'. I am getting this error

Comment: @ITresearcher -https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setExperimentalOption-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object- there you go, seems like not yet exposed to ChromeOptions API

Comment: @ITresearcher : yeah it seems like was moving in depth to java, searched for dot-net equivalents and updated the answer. Not certain it would solve, but would surely be a use case.

Comment: @nullpointer not working. I think that setting is for chromium